# Proving a sum of a strange series $ \sum_{i=1}^{n} 11i^{10}-55i^9+165i^8-330i^7+462i^6 -462i^5+330i^4-165i^3+55i^2-11i+1 = n^{11} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, harmonic-analysis, binomial-theorem, telescopic-series

While messing around with zeta functions I encountered a strange sum:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} 11i^{10}-55i^9+165i^8-330i^7+462i^6 -462i^5+330i^4-165i^3+55i^2-11i+1 = n^{11}
$$

How should I approach proving that this equality is true for all $n,i \in \mathbb{N}$ ? I ran this for a few values on some engines and it does work for every number I tried.

Comment: if you prove that it's sum is a polynomial of degree at most 11, then just plugging in 11 values will prove the equality

Comment: The clean way to do this is diagonals in Pascal's triangle. the sum of $k$ choose 1  up to some $n$ is $n+1$  choose 2, that sort of idea. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_moment

Comment: @WillJagy Pascals triangle assumes that the highest power on both sides is equal if i remember correctly - in the above expression I have highest power of 10 while on the right it is 11.

Comment: dvdf, what is the sum for $k$ from $3$to $n$ of $k$ choose $3 \; ? \; \;$

Comment: This is pretty standard. Verifying a formula $\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(i)=g(n)$ is equivalent to proving the much easier result $f(n) =g(n) - g(n-1)$ and $g(0)=0$. But I admit this approach is boring enough to prove common formulas like $\sum i=n(n+1)/2$ and $\sum i^2=n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-(i-1)^{11}+i^{11})$$ and use the telescoping summation.

I used the following $$(x-1)^{11}=x^{11}-11x^{10}+55x^9-165x^8+330x^7-462x^6+462x^5-330x^4+165x^3-55x^2+11x-1$$ and $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-(i-1)^{11}+i^{11})=1^{11}-0^{11}+2^{11}-1^{11}+...+n^{11}-(n-1)^{11}=n^{11}.$$

Comment: excuse my ignorance here, but Im not sure that I understand what you propose.

Comment: @dvd280 each element cancels the previous one, so you are only left with the last one

Comment: @dvd280 I added something. See now.

Comment: @dvd280 This approach can be equivalently turned into the proof by induction. The main step is to notice that $11n^{10}-55i^9+\ldots-11n+1=n^{11}-(n-1)^{11}$, which follows from the binomial formula.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg, can you please explain how you got to that equality? You just noticed it randomly?

Comment: @BinyaminR I used a binomial of Newton. For example $\binom{11}{5}=462.$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg but the Newton binomial assumes both sides have equal highest powers no? here the left side has a highest power which is one less

Comment: @dvd280 See please better your question. $i^{11}-i^{11}=0.$ I used $(a+b)^n,$ where $a=i$, $b=-1$ and $n=11$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Well I guess I am too stupid to understand where your equality came from and how its applied here, but thank you.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg right, I just wondered how you noticed that it would work. It definitely gave a nice answer.

Comment: @dvd280 if you want a general way to solve this type of sum look at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417156/finding-formula-for-partial-sum-of-polynomial-terms . once you understand what degree of a polynomial the sum is, you can just solve it's coefficients

Comment: @BinyaminR It seems that it's a binomial expansion. I just checked that it's indeed $x^{11}-(x-1)^{11}.$

Answer (score 2):

factorial moments. As cumulative sums along a diagonal...

[image]

factorial moments.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Will, I was interested in this because I was surprised to find out that $\sum_{i=1}^{n^k} P= n^{k^{2}}$ or that for the polynomial above, $\sum_{i=1}^{n^{11}} P= n^{121}$

Comment: @dvd280, if you know (or can find lyrics) of the traditional Twelve Days of Christmas song, the number of gifts given on day $n$ is $n+1$ choose $2$ while the cumulative gifts up to day $n$ is $n+2$ choose $3.$  I remember my father, about 1995, demanding what $14$ had to do with it, but the total gifts really is $14$ choose $3$ or $364$ Given your question, I think that is a really good exercise for you, maybe by computer, whatever, confirm my Twelve Days claims.